# Get the size of the rectangle within a UIView with a cornerRadius

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView with rounded corners.

How can I get the size of the inner rectangle?

Comment: You mean so that an inner rectangles corners would touch the inside of each rounded corner?

Comment: I mean I want to know the size of the rectangle that would appear if we were removing the rounded part. On each side, as soon as I reach the curve, I want to know where I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to be able to get something like the green rectangle [here](http://pasteboard.co/1PocMr66.png). You can use this method, where you pass the red rectangle as parameter:

```
func innerRectangle(view:UIView) -> CGRect {
    let radius = view.layer.cornerRadius * (1 - M_SQRT1_2)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.origin.x + radius, y: view.frame.origin.y + radius)
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-radius*2, height: view.frame.height-radius*2)
    return CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe your code would return the area of the green rectangle in your image. For example, if `cornerRadius == 0.5f * view.frame.size.width` then your returned `CGRect` would have an area of 0 and `origin.x == 0.5f * view.frame.size.width` and neither of those statements would be true. I believe some trigonometry is needed to accurately return the `CGRect` of the green rectangle.

Comment: @Fennelouski thanks for putting the link inline. however, I don't believe you tested your code. it is not correct. apart from you calculation, decreasing width by the same value you increase origin, does not make sense already. I will turn back to my implementation, it works and is tested. please give it a try in Playground

Comment: I will do that now, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I missed the `CGFloat(M_PI)` division of the radius. That is so much simpler and more elegant than the solution I was proposing. Excellent answer!

Comment: thanks @Fennelouski for suggestion, unfortunately I can't review yet, but I edited the answer according to it

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a great estimate for small values of `cornerRadius`, but it deviates noticeably from the outer rect's boundary as the value increases. Since the OP requested that the inner rect must touch the outer rect, it would be better to replace the first line inside the function with

```
let radius = view.layer.cornerRadius * (1 - (1 / pow(2, 0.5)))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]